# ERROR Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () en angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest

[image: Errors I get]

ERRORS:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:8080/login","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/login: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at zone-evergreen.js:707
    at SafeSubscriber._error (Observable.js:91)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:135)
    at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at FilterSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:7187
```

POST service in JAVA spring boot (URL of the microservice: http:localhost:8080/login):

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class dmoController {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody String data) {
    System.out.print("entra");
    System.out.print(data);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    
}
```

Call to post from Angular (url angular: http:localhost:4200/login):

```
  public async login(email: string, password: string) {
        const data = { username: 'pepa', password: 'manoli' };

        httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        httpOptions.headers.append(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
            'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
        );
        httpOptions.headers.append(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'X-Requested-With,content-type',
        );
        httpOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(data), httpOptions).toPromise();
    }
```

Comment: Please write your question in English.

Comment: Hola Maria! bienvenida a stackoverflow. Si no hablas ingles, puedes poner tu pregunta aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @CodIng59 you need to be more kind to people on stackoverflow buddy. Make her feel welcome and point her to the right direction or ask her in a polite way to change her question to english.

Comment: Have you considered looking up HTTP status 403?

Answer (score 0):

Resolving Cors is not a client-side thing since it's your localhost development, the request origin will be different.
you need to configure the server such a way that it should allow the request from all origins.

Take a look at this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ you might find some insights.

Comment: Configuring the server for cros is not what I have already set? this: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

Comment: can you paste the complete request and the header payload?

Comment: I've left it that way and it doesn't work either:                                                                     
 public async login(email: string, password: string) {
        const data = { username: 'pepa', password: 'manoli' };
        this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(data), httpOptions).toPromise();
    }

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody String data) {
 System.out.print("entra");
 System.out.print(data);
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
 headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
 return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

Comment: try something like this:



    this.http.post(ConstantData.loginUrl, {email,password, httpOptions: httpOptions }).toPromise();


and try to capture the request payload that you are sending to the server.
you can find that payload information upon right-click > Inspect > Network block.
upon clicking the log in button the packets sent from Client will be seen in this block.